# Expressions with no side effects in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

See, what I don't get is, why should programs like the following be legal?

```
int main()
{ 
    static const int i = 0;
    i < i > i;
}
```

I mean, surely, nobody *actually* has any current programs that have expressions with no side effects in them, since that would be very pointless, and it would make parsing & compiling the language much easier. So why not just disallow them? What benefit does the language actually gain from allowing this kind of syntax?

Another example being like this:

```
int main() {
    static const int i = 0;
    int x = (i);
}
```

What is the actual benefit of such statements?

And things like the most vexing parse. Does anybody, ever, declare functions in the middle of other functions? I mean, we got rid of things like implicit function declaration, and things like that. Why not just get rid of them for C++0x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it would make parsing & compiling the
>   language much easier

I don't see how. Why is it easier to parse and compile `i < i > i` if you're *required* to issue a diagnostic, than it is to parse it if you're allowed to do anything you damn well please provided that the emitted code has no side-effects?

The Java compiler forbids unreachable code (as opposed to code with no effect), which is a mixed blessing for the programmer, and requires a little bit of extra work from the compiler than what a C++ compiler is actually required to do (basic block dependency analysis). Should C++ forbid unreachable code? Probably not. Even though C++ compilers certainly do enough optimization to identify unreachable basic blocks, in some cases they may do too much. Should `if (foo) { ...}` be an illegal unreachable block if `foo` is a false compile-time constant? What if it's not a compile-time constant, but the optimizer has figured out how to calculate the value, should it be legal and the compiler has to realise that the reason it's removing it is implementation-specific, so as not to give an error? More special cases.

> nobody actually has any current
>   programs that have expressions with no
>   side effects in them

Loads. For example, if `NDEBUG` is true, then `assert` expands to a void expression with no effect. So that's yet more special cases needed in the compiler to permit *some* useless expressions, but not others.

The rationale, I believe, is that if it expanded to nothing then (a) compilers would end up throwing warnings for things like `if (foo) assert(bar);`, and (b) code like this would be legal in release but not in debug, which is just confusing:

```
assert(foo) // oops, forgot the semi-colon
foo.bar();
```

> things like the most vexing parse

That's why it's called "vexing". It's a backward-compatibility issue really. If C++ now changed the meaning of those vexing parses, the meaning of existing code would change. Not much existing code, as you point out, but the C++ committee takes a fairly strong line on backward compatibility. If you want a language that changes every five minutes, use Perl ;-)

Anyway, it's too late now. Even if we had some great insight that the C++0x committee had missed, why some feature should be removed or incompatibly changed, they aren't going to break anything in the FCD unless the FCD is definitively in error.

Note that for all of your suggestions, any compiler could issue a warning for them (actually, I don't understand what your problem is with the second example, but certainly for useless expressions and for vexing parses in function bodies). If you're right that nobody does it deliberately, the warnings would cause no harm. If you're wrong that nobody does it deliberately, your stated case for removing them is incorrect. Warnings in popular compilers could pave the way for removing a feature, especially since the standard is authored largely by compiler-writers. The fact that we don't always get warnings for these things suggests to me that there's more to it than you think.

Answer (score 8):

Probably because banning then would make the specification more complex, which would make compilers more complex.

Comment: Except that if the compiler has two ways it could parse a statement, but one of them is illegal, then it knows that it must be the other, which is simple, whereas if the Standard allows both, then the compiler has to decide which, which is far less simple. The less viable programs there are, the less logic you need to decide which you have.

Comment: That isn't always true though, since compilers are required to detect certain invalid expressions and report appropriate error messages. In any cases like you are suggesting it certainly can't assume that the code is valid.

Answer (score 3):

- It's convenient sometimes to put useless statements into a program and compile it just to make sure they're legal - e.g. that the types involve can be resolved/matched etc.
- Especially in generated code (macros as well as more elaborate external mechanisms, templates where Policies or types may introduce meaningless expansions in some no-op cases), having less special uncompilable cases to avoid keeps things simpler
- There may be some temporarily commented code that removes the meaningful usage of a variable, but it could be a pain to have to similarly identify and comment all the variables that aren't used elsewhere.
- While in your examples you show the variables being "int" immediately above the pointless usage, in practice the types may be much more complicated (e.g. operator<()) and whether the operations have side effects may even be unknown to the compiler (e.g. out-of-line functions), so any benefit's limited to simpler cases.
- C++ needs a good reason to break backwards (and retained C) compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Why should doing nothing be treated as a special case? Furthermore, whilst the above cases are easy to spot, one could imagine far more complicated programs where it's not so easy to identify that there are no side effects.

Answer (score 0):

As an iteration of the C++ standard, C++0x have to be backward compatible. Nobody can assert that the statements you wrote does not exist in some piece of critical software written/owned by, say, NASA or DoD.

Anyway regarding your very first example, the *parser* cannot assert that `i` is a static constant expression, and that `i < i > i` is a useless expression -- e.g. if `i` is a templated type, `i < i > i` is an "invalid variable declaration", not a "useless computation", and still not a parse error.

Comment: Nobody says that NASA or DoD has to upgrade to C++0x. If they like it, then they can keep C++03. The old compiler versions won't magically disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the operator was overloaded to have side effects like `cout<<i;` This is the reason why they cannot be removed now. On the other hand C# forbids non-assignment or method calls expresions to be used as statements and I believe this is a good thing as it makes the code more clear and semantically correct. However C# had the opportunity to forbid this from the very beginning which C++ does not.

Answer (score 0):

Expressions with no side effects can turn up more often than you think in templated and macro code.  If you've ever declared `std::vector<int>`, you've instantiated template code with no side effects.  `std::vector` must destruct all its elements when releasing itself, in case you stored a class for type `T`.  This requires, at some point, a statement similar to `ptr->~T();` to invoke the destructor.  `int` has no destructor though, so the call has no side effects and will be removed entirely by the optimizer.  It's also likely it will be inside a loop, then the entire loop has no side effects, so the entire loop is removed by the optimizer.

So if you disallowed expressions with no side effects, `std::vector<int>` **wouldn't work**, for one.

Another common case is `assert(a == b)`.  In release builds you want these asserts to disappear - but you can't re-define them as an empty macro, otherwise statements like `if (x) assert(a == b);` suddenly put the next statement in to the if statement - a disaster!  In this case `assert(x)` can be redefined as `((void)0)`, which is a statement that has no side effects.  Now the `if` statement works correctly in release builds too - it just does nothing.

These are just two common cases.  There are many more you probably don't know about.  So, while expressions with no side effects seem redundant, they're actually functionally important.  An optimizer will remove them entirely so there's no performance impact, too.